# Unity Android Plugin is called even after exiting the application

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have made a plugin that shows Toast and Alert on Android in Unity Android App. The app shows ***"Press back button again to exit."*** when hardware Back Button is pressed on starting scene. The problem is that when Back button is pressed twice, the app exits and Toast is shown twice. That means Toast is shown even after the app exits. What is the cause of this.

**Here is my C# code:**

```cs
const string pluginName = "com.jk.pluginexample.MyPlugin";
static AndroidJavaClass pluginClass;
static AndroidJavaObject pluginInstance;

bool isPaused = false;
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        if (!isPaused)
        {
            isPaused = true;
            ShowToast("Press back button again to exit.");
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }
    }
}

public static AndroidJavaClass PluginClass
{
    get
    {
        if (pluginClass == null)
        {
            pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass(pluginName);
            AndroidJavaClass playerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            AndroidJavaObject activity = playerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
            pluginClass.SetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("mainActivity", activity);
        }
        return pluginClass;
    }
}

public static AndroidJavaObject PluginInstance
{
    get
    {
        if (pluginInstance == null)
        {
            pluginInstance = PluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getInstance");
        }
        return pluginInstance;
    }
}

public static void ShowToast(string message)
{
    PluginInstance.Call("showToast", new object[] { message });
}
```

**Here is my Android Java Code:**

```java
public void showToast(String message)
{
    Toast.makeText(mainActivity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
}
```

Comment: If it is not hard can you provider whole class. Or check if you have OnApplicationExit function  somewhere else

Comment: @phantasm, there is nothing in the class besides the code I provided, only class definition and all. Also I haven't implemented `OnApplicationExit()` anywhere. I have also tried using WRP Plugin for Toast and Alert from asset store, but same result.